# How can I cache dynamic urls in service worker? Does it has anything to do with precache? I am using ReactJS default serviceWorker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In my Main.js file I have below code:

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
/*
some code
*/
ReactDOM.render(<Main />,document.getElementById('app'));
serviceWorker.register()
```

This serviceWorker it is created by default from create-react-app operation but I had to copy it from source since I didn't create app using create-react-app.

serviceWorker looks for 'service-worker.js' file inside / scope. In the following line:

```
const swUrl = `/service-worker.js`;
```

Using this configuration I am able to cache all that is mentioned in service-worker.js file's PrecacheConfig variable, such as /js/app.js

When it comes to a dynamic url such as `/myapp/{id}/test/`. I know for sure Pre caching should not be done for all these dynamic urls and they should be cached when a user visits the page but then where and how do I cache them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Workbox https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox to manage your Service Worker functionality. Using workbox.routing module (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing) you can specify custom rules for cashing by using specific to your app regular expressions.

Hope it will help you!